# Getting error 'check' function not defined

Tags: javascript, html

I aqm new to HTML and Javascript. My aim is to build a Password checker. I used the code from this link http://curiositybeyondcontrol.blogspot.ie/2012/04/password-strength-indication-using.html as a base for the below given code. When I ran the original it ran fine. But when I run my version, it keeps saying 'check' function is not defined.
Kindly guide me as to where I should correct this code.

Please find my code given below:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Password strength</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function check(x)
{
  var pstring = String(x);
  var level = 0;
  var plength = pstring.length;
  var p1 = /[a-z]/;
  var p2 = /[A-Z]/;
  var p3 = /[0-9]/;
  var p4 = /[\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\-\_\=\+\[\{\]\}\|\\\;\:\'\"\,\<\.\>\/\?\`\~]/;
  if(p1.test(x))
    level++;
  if(p2.test(x))
    level++;
  if(p3.test(x))
    level++;
  if(p4.test(x))
    level++;
  prog_bar(plength,level,200,5,"#0066FF","#99FFFF");
}

function prog_bar(pass_length,pass_level,width,height,border,fill)
 {
var str = "",numdays = 0;

if(pass_length = 1 && pass_level = 1)
  numdays = 0;
else if(pass_length = 1 && pass_level = 2)
  numdays = 0;
else if(pass_length = 1 && pass_level = 3)
  numdays = 0;
else if(pass_length = 1 && pass_level = 4)
  numdays = 0; 
else if(pass_length = 2 && pass_level = 1)
  numdays = 0;
else if(pass_length = 2 && pass_level = 2)
  numdays = 0;
else if(pass_length = 2 && pass_level = 3)
  numdays = 0;
else if(pass_length = 2 && pass_level = 4)
  numdays = 0; 
else if(pass_length = 3 && pass_level = 1)
  numdays = 0;
else if(pass_length = 3 && pass_level = 2)
  numdays = 0;
else if(pass_length = 3 && pass_level = 3)
  numdays = 0;
else if(pass_length = 3 && pass_level = 4)
  numdays = 0; 
else if(pass_length = 4 && pass_level = 1)
  numdays = 0;
else if(pass_length = 4 && pass_level = 2)
  numdays = 0;
else if(pass_length = 4 && pass_level = 3)
  numdays = 0;
else if(pass_length = 4 && pass_level = 4)
  numdays = 0;
else if(pass_length = 5 && pass_level = 1)
  numdays = 0;
else if(pass_length = 5 && pass_level = 2)
  numdays = 0;
else if(pass_length = 5 && pass_level = 3)
  numdays = 0;
else if(pass_length = 5 && pass_level = 4)
  numdays = 0;
else if(pass_length = 6 && pass_level = 1)
  numdays = 0;
else if(pass_length = 6 && pass_level = 2)
  numdays = 0;
else if(pass_length = 6 && pass_level = 3)
  numdays = 0;
else if(pass_length = 6 && pass_level = 4)
  numdays = 0;
else if(pass_length = 7 && pass_level = 1)
  numdays = 0;
else if(pass_length = 7 && pass_level = 2)
  numdays = 0;
else if(pass_length = 7 && pass_level = 3)
  numdays = 0;
else if(pass_length = 7 && pass_level = 4)
  numdays = 0;
else if(pass_length = 8 && pass_level = 1)
  numdays = 0;
else if(pass_length = 8 && pass_level = 2)
  numdays = 0;
else if(pass_length = 8 && pass_level = 3)
  numdays = 0;
else if(pass_length = 8 && pass_level = 4)
  numdays = 0;
else if(pass_length = 9 && pass_level = 1)
  numdays = 0;
else if(pass_length = 9 && pass_level = 2)
  numdays = 0;
else if(pass_length = 9 && pass_level = 3)
  numdays = 0;
else if(pass_length = 9 && pass_level = 4)
  numdays = 1;
else if(pass_length = 10 && pass_level = 1)
  numdays = 0;
else if(pass_length = 10 && pass_level = 2)
  numdays = 0;
else if(pass_length = 10 && pass_level = 3)
  numdays = 1;
else if(pass_length = 10 && pass_level = 4)
  numdays = 70;
else if(pass_length = 11 && pass_level = 1)
  numdays = 0;
else if(pass_length = 11 && pass_level = 2)
  numdays = 11;
else if(pass_length = 11 && pass_level = 3)
  numdays = 75;
else if(pass_length = 11 && pass_level = 4)
  numdays = 6512;
else if(pass_length = 12 && pass_level = 1)
  numdays = 0;
else if(pass_length = 12 && pass_level = 2)
  numdays = 11;
else if(pass_length = 12 && pass_level = 3)
  numdays = 75;
else if(pass_length = 12 && pass_level = 4)
  numdays = 6512;
else if(pass_length = 13 && pass_level = 1)
  numdays = 4;
else if(pass_length = 13 && pass_level = 2)
  numdays = 29406;
else if(pass_length = 13 && pass_level = 3)
  numdays = 289393;
else if(pass_length = 13 && pass_level = 4)
  numdays = 56321550;
else if(pass_length = 14 && pass_level = 1)
  numdays = 93;
else if(pass_length = 14 && pass_level = 2)
  numdays = 1529125;
else if(pass_length = 14 && pass_level = 3)
  numdays = 17942375;
else if(pass_length = 14 && pass_level = 4)
  numdays = 5237904191;
else if(pass_length = 15 && pass_level = 1)
  numdays = 2427;
else if(pass_length = 15 && pass_level = 2)
  numdays = 79514517;
else if(pass_length = 15 && pass_level = 3)
  numdays = 1112427235;
else if(pass_length = 15 && pass_level = 4)
  numdays = 487125089774;
else if(pass_length = 16 && pass_level = 1)
  numdays = 63091;
else if(pass_length = 16 && pass_level = 2)
  numdays = 4134754882;
else if(pass_length = 16 && pass_level = 3)
  numdays = 68970488580;
else 
  numdays = 45302633348959;

if(numdays<=11)
  fill = "#FF0000";
else if(numdays<=600)
  fill = "#FFFF00";
else
  fill = "#00FF00";
str = str + "<div style=\"border:"+border+" solid thin; width:"+width+"px; height:"+height+"px;\">";
str = str + "<div style=\"background-color:"+fill+"; width:"+res+"%; height:"+height+"px;\">";
str = str + "</div></div>";
if(numdays<=11)
  str = str + "Easy";
else if(numdays<=600)
  str = str + "A Bit Tough";
else
  str = str + "Unbreakable";
document.getElementById("prog_bar").innerHTML = str;

}

</script>
</head>


<body>
This password checker checks the strength of your password as well as  
<br />the number of days a hacker would take to break your password<br /><br />
Password : <input type="password" onkeyup="check(this.value)" /><br /><br />
<div id="prog_bar"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: what about using a switch?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp

Comment: seems to work in fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5juKs/1/

Comment: Hello Enjoyted and Nicholas V. Would that be a reason for this error?

Comment: Hello Huangism. I guess then the error is in a syntax that I have used in the rest of the code and not necessarily in the check function

Comment: @Manus yes I believe so. Your check function should be called on keyup if this is all of your code, I don't see what can cause it to be undefined. Do you see any errors in the console? Try removing extra js codes and leaving only check and see if it works

Comment: @Manus - careful not to confuse `==` (comparison equals) with `=` (assignment equals) That is to say, a single `=` assigns a value, while `==` checks to see if two values are equivalent.

Comment: Thanks enhzflep. Chaning the = to == in the if conditions worked. Now I will also see how to use switch in this code.

Comment: Hi guys, the code works just by changing the = to ==. But now I have a different problem. When I enter a value in the box it gets checked and the right values are displayed. But if i delete that value then a wrong value is displayed. How do I stop this from happening?